# Write the PowerShell script using runbook to take the snapshot of the VM: Run as Account: Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook

I am trying new things using runbook in automated way
Write the powerShell script using runbook which have to take the snapshot of the VM(s disk nd data disk) through RUN AS ACCOUNT, which connects to az account using the service principal and listing them the snapshots

any idea or help, Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I tried to create the snapshot vm using PowerShell in the runbook in my environment and got the below results*

*I have the automation account with newly created runbook*

*Created the vm with same resource group
Before creating the run book I have added the modules called ***az.acount*** and **az.compute** if we add the modules then only runbook will work*

[image]

*If there is no modules found have to import the modules from the browse gallery*

*Below is my PowerShell script to create to the snapshot of the vm which connects the AZ account using the service principal and listing the snapshots*

```
Param
(
    [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
    [string]$VmResourceGroup,
    [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
    [string]$VmName
)

$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName
    Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
$vm = get-azvm -Name $VmName -ResourceGroupName $VmResourceGroup
$snapscreated = @()

Write-Output "VM $($vm.name) OS Disk Snapshot Begin"
$snapshotdisk = $vm.StorageProfile

$OSDiskSnapshotConfig = New-AzSnapshotConfig -SourceUri $snapshotdisk.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.id -CreateOption Copy -Location australiaeast # -OsType Windows
$snapshotNameOS = "snap_$($snapshotdisk.OsDisk.Name)_snap_osdisk_$(Get-Date -Format ddMMyyhhmm)"

New-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $VmResourceGroup -SnapshotName $snapshotNameOS -Snapshot $OSDiskSnapshotConfig -ErrorAction Stop
$snapscreated += $snapshotNameOS

Write-Output "VM $($vm.name) OS Disk Snapshot End"
Write-Output "=====================================" 
 
Write-Output "VM $($vm.name) Data Disk Snapshots Begin"
 
$dataDisks = ($snapshotdisk.DataDisks).name

foreach ($datadisk in $datadisks) {

    $dataDisk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -DiskName $datadisk

    Write-Output "VM $($vm.name) data Disk $($datadisk.Name) Snapshot Begin"

    $DataDiskSnapshotConfig = New-AzSnapshotConfig -SourceUri $dataDisk.Id -CreateOption Copy -Location australiaeast
    $snapshotNameData = "snap_$($datadisk.name)_snap_datadisk_$(Get-Date -Format ddMMyyhhmm)"

    New-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $VmResourceGroup -SnapshotName $snapshotNameData -Snapshot $DataDiskSnapshotConfig -ErrorAction Stop

    $snapscreated += $snapshotNameData
    
    Write-Output "VM $($vm.name) data Disk $($datadisk.Name) Snapshot End"   
    Write-Output "====================================="
}
Write-Output "VM $($vm.name) Data Disk Snapshots End" 
Write-Output "List of Snaps created for VM $($vm.name) : -"
$snapscreated
Write-Output "====================================="
```

***The above code I have taken from the [schowdary22](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/schoudhary22/Shailender-YouTube-Videos/main/Azure-Automation-Run-As/vm-snap-run-as-account.ps1)***

*While running the script I have given the rg_name and virtual machine name*

[image]

*After succeed I am able to see snap list as shown in below*

[image]

Comment: Thank you @komali Annem for the Help. I tried and it worked for me. I have one more doubt can we do it in managed identity instead of run as account

Comment: @johnmd yes we can do using managed identity instead of run as account